# CSS Style Sheet is Not Working?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in my stylesheet...

```
body 
{        
    background-image:url('Background.png');
}

td.Header
{
    background: purple Url("Header.png");
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:blue;
}
```

Now This is how I use it in my html:

```
<table align="center" width="800px">
    <tr>
        <td class="header" height="100px">Where's my background and border?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The Normal Stuff </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I do have my stylesheet linked to my html file. The only thing that works on my css sheet is my body class. My background image is appearing for my body. But for my td.header nothing at all is working. Please help.

Thanks Alot

Comment: works fine for me as an internally declared style, the only thing I could think of would be to make the casing of the "header" style match between the stylesheet declaration and the use in your td, I think this can cause problems in some browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS can be case sensitive. If you are using the XHTML doctype, then CSS class names *are* case sensitive, so a class name of `header` is not the same as `Header`.

Check if you're using a doctype of XHTML.  If so, you'll need to change your class attribute in the html to exactly match the class selector in the stylesheet.

If your DOCTYPE is HTML though, case sensitivity doesn't matter, and something else is going on.

Note that HTML5, like XHTML, will also be case sensitive.

Comment: I was checking out the [WHATWG entry](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#case-sensitivity) regarding case sensitivity. Seems like the only way to ensure case-insensitive is to intentionally trigger quirks mode. Wikipedia has a good entry on, which [types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) to use.

Answer (score 2):

CSS class names are case-sensitive. If you change "td.Header" to "td.header", does it work?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is your css rule

```
td.Header
```

css is case sensitive so it should be the same case as your HTML:

```
td.header
```

second, in CSS you dont need to use quotes for urls. In fact i read somewhere that its better not to (cant recall where or i'd cite it :)

Answer (score 0):

in your css write `td.header`, because **class names and ids are case-sensitive**.